# In a calculator project trouble making the "backspace" function

Tags: javascript, html

This is the HTML code and here the "CE" button i want to perform as a backspace.

HTML code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Calculetor</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculetor.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="calculator">
                <div id="result">

                    <p id="input"></p>
                    <p id="output"></p>

                </div>
                <div class="keyboard">
                    <button class="operator" id="clear">C</button>
                    <button class="operator" id="backspace">CE</button>
                    <button class="operator" id="%">%</button>
                    <button class="operator" id="/">/</button>
                    <button class="number" value="7">7</button>
                    <button class="number" value="8">8</button>
                    <button class="number" value="9">9</button>
                    <button class="operator" id="*">*</button>
                    <button class="number" value="4">4</button>
                    <button class="number" value="5">5</button>
                    <button class="number" value="6">6</button>
                    <button class="operator" id="-">-</button>
                    <button class="number" value="1">1</button>
                    <button class="number" value="2">2</button>
                    <button class="number" value="3">3</button>
                    <button class="operator" id="+">+</button>
                    <button class="operator" id="log">log</button>
                    <button class="number" value="0">0</button>
                    <button class="operator" id="!">!</button>
                    <button class="operator" id="=">=</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="calculetor.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this JS code in faction back() i want to write the logic of the backspace. Delete last character from input, however I would like to stick with JavaScript only without jquery.

JavaScript Code

```
let screen_input = document.getElementById("input1");
buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".keyboard");
let screen_output = document.getElementById("output");
screen_input = "";
for (item of buttons) {
    item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
     buttonsText = e.target.innerText;
    console.log(buttonsText);

    if (buttonsText === "=") {
      screen_output.textContent = eval(screen_input);
    } else if (buttonsText === "C") {
      screen_output.textContent = " ";
      screen_input = "";
    } else if (buttonsText === "CE") {
     function back();//here i want to put the backspace logic
    } else {
      screen_input += buttonsText;
      screen_output.textContent = screen_input;
    }})};
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to perform an action when button pressed right?
Here is an example:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
if(event.keyCode == 8){
console.log("backspace pressed")
}
});
```

Edit: You need to click in the snippet to make the code work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but actually i want to do that when I pressed "CE" in user interface(HTML)then then last character will delete whenever it is a number or operator..